# Wicket: Create IResourceStream for byte[]

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I'm using `Wicket` and I have to implement this method that returns an `IResourceStream` :

```
protected IResourceStream getResourceStream() {
        protected IResourceStream getResourceStream() {
            try {
                byte[] data = getMyData(); /* returns a byte[] of data */

                return ???? //What should I use here?
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that I cannot find an implementation of `IResourceStream` that uses a Byte Array input.
All I can find is `StringResourceStream` which wants a String as input (I tried using that by passing a new `String(data)`, but it corrupts my data) and `FileResourceStream` that wants a `File` as input (which I don't have, since I have the data in-memory)

What should I be using here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `AbstractResourceStream` that returns `ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)`.

Feel free to create a ticket at Wicket JIRA if you want this to be included in the distro.